# Greasemonkey testing if array element exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, greasemonkey

I'm writing a script that adds labels to things on a page using an element from an array based on part of the link... so my array looks like this:

```
var componentList[9] = "Sunnyseed"
var componentList[10] = "Echoberry"
var componentList[11] = "Riverstone"
var componentList[13] = "Auraglass"
var componentList[14] = "Skypollen"
```

You'll notice there is no '12'...  I want the label to be 'Unknown' when the array item doesn't exist.  Now, I can't exactly test my solution since I can't cause the target page to throw me a 12... so I was hoping somebody would tell me whether this will do what I want or not...

```
 var component = ""

 if(typeof componentList[critterIDval] == 'undefined'){
 component="Unknown"
 }

else{

 component=componentList[critterIDval]
}
```

This is obviously not the full script, but it should be the important stuff...  I just want to know if that will make it say 'Unknown' when the critterIDval is 12 - since it could take years to come across the situation for testing.

Comment: will string value be an empty string

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking... critterIDval will always be a number... but that number may not exist as an array element

Comment: what I was asking was about the value part like `componentList[14] = '';`

Comment: `typeof componentList[critterIDval] = 'undefined'` is wrong. That is an *assignment* (and should result in a syntax error), not a comparison (i.e. `==` or `===`). Also, a little bit of formatting makes code a good bit more readable.

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, if the element exists it will not have an empty string value.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for seeing that... I copied that line from somewhere but it was != and of course I wanted to test if it DID equal... I always do that...

Comment: in that case see my answer below `var component = componentList[critterIDval] || 'Unknown'`... this could be a better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You're using a single-equals sign in your comparison, so that will mess it up, and I'm not sure you can create a JS array like that, but aside from that, you're good.

[Here is the test I ran for it:](http://jsfiddle.net/2YUb7/1/)

```
var componentList = [];
componentList[9] = "Sunnyseed";
componentList[10] = "Echoberry";
componentList[11] = "Riverstone";
componentList[13] = "Auraglass";
componentList[14] = "Skypollen";

for (var critterIDval = 9; critterIDval < 15; critterIDval++) {
    if (typeof componentList[critterIDval] == 'undefined') { // double equals here
        component = "Unknown";
    } else {
        component = componentList[critterIDval];
    }
    console.log(component);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the = thing... I have a bad habit of that...  and it never occurred to me to test it by running a loop... now I feel dumb... thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice a main difference between your code and mine until I had to hunt down a "missing ; before..." error... I had to remove the var from 751 var componentList[] statements that I wrote before posting my question lol

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine.

Though if you are sure that the value will never be an empty string(like `componentList[14] = '';`) then you can try

```
var component = componentList[critterIDval] || 'Unknown'
```

Comment: That will also return 'Unknown' if the value is `0`, `null`, `NaN` or `false` in addition to `undefined`.

Comment: @RobG since it is a string value it is fine `'0' || 'Unknown'` will give `'0'` same for `'false' || 'Unknown'`

Comment: I honestly forget what '||' does

Answer (score 1):

> I want the label to be 'Unknown' when the array item doesn't exist.

The *typeof* operator does not tell you if a property exists or not as it returns *undefined* when the property doesn't exist but also when it does exist and has been assigned a the value `undefined` or simply created but hasn't been assigned a value.

There are two primary ways to test for the existence of a property: the `in` operator, which also looks on the `[[Prototype]]` chain and the `hasOwnProperty` method of all Objects. So

```
if (componentList.hasOwnProperty(critterIDval)) {
  component = "Unknown"

} else {
  component = componentList[critterIDval]
}
```

which you could also write as:

```
component = componentList.hasOwnProperty(critterIDval)? componentList[critterIDval] : 'unknown';
```

PS. there are other methods, such as looking at `Object.keys(componentList)` and `componentList.propertyIsEnumerable(critterIDval)`, but the above are the most common.

#### Edit

If your requirement is not just to test for property existence but to also test for a "truthy" value, then:

```
if (componentList[critterIDval])
```

may be sufficient and will return false where the value is `''` (empty string), `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined` or `null`.

Maybe just testing for a non–empty string or number will do:

```
if (/.+/.test(componentList[critterIDval]))
```

but that returns `true` for `NaN`, `null` and so on. So you need to specify what you are actually testing for, otherwise you may get undesired results for some values.

Comment: Well, the desired result would actually be to have it say "unknown" in all of those cases, so the 'typeof' actually will work perfectly... for future projects I WILL check out your methods, as I'm sure I'll want different results on other projects...